# How to create a XSLT that removes only those elements from XML whose attribute value is contained in a list of XPATH selected values

Tags: xslt

I need to create a XLST that removes unwanted elements from an input XML. The elements to filter “Subelement” are identified by the attribute “RelevantForFiltering”. Apart from removing those elements, there are also other elements in the input XML “SubelementReference” that are referencing to the “Subelement” items by the “Target” attribute. They must also be removed.

I already created this XSLT consisting of an identity transformation. Matching templates remove the wanted elements from the XML. But now I am facing the problem, that currently the used “contains” function selects also those “SubelementReference” elements that contain only a substring of the identified ID. In the example below the “SubelementReference” with the Target “SubElem01” is also removed.
I searched several forums I couldn’t find a solution to realize this. There are comparable questions but in those examples it is checked that the attribute value is contained in a list of static attribute values that are known already while XSLT creation. Thank you in advance for suggestions.

#### Input xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
  <ListOfElements>
    <Element ID="Element01">
      <UseableSubelements>
        <SubelementReference Target="A-SubElem01, AB" />
        <SubelementReference Target="SubElem01" />
        <SubelementReference Target="A-SubElem02, AB" />
        <SubelementReference Target="A-SubElem03, AB" />
      </UseableSubelements>
    </Element>
    <Element ID="Element02">
      <UseableSubelements>
        <SubelementReference Target="A-SubElem01, AB" />
        <SubelementReference Target="SubElem01" />
        <SubelementReference Target="A-SubElem02, AB" />
      </UseableSubelements>
    </Element>
  </ListOfElements>
  <ListOfSubelements>
    <Subelement ID="A-SubElem01, AB" RelevantForFiltering="true"/>
    <Subelement ID="SubElem01" RelevantForFiltering="false"/>
    <Subelement ID="A-SubElem02, AB" RelevantForFiltering="true"/>
    <Subelement ID="A-SubElem03, AB" RelevantForFiltering="true"/>
  </ListOfSubelements>
</Document>
```

#### XSLT

```xml
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

<!-- Identity transformation -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Select items to filter. Separate them by “;” character (tried also to find a solution with tokenize fucntion without any success) -->
<xsl:variable name="SubelementsToFilter">
  <xsl:value-of select="//Subelement[@RelevantForFiltering='true']/@ID" separator=";"/>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- Remove Subelements -> working fine -->
<xsl:template match="Subelement[@RelevantForFiltering='true']"/>
<!-- Remove SubelementReferences -> too many items are removed -->
<xsl:template match="Element/UseableSubelements/SubelementReference[contains($SubelementsToFilter,@Target)]"/>
```

#### Current XML output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
    <ListOfElements>
        <Element ID="Element01">
            <UseableSubelements/>
        </Element>
        <Element ID="Element02">
            <UseableSubelements/>
        </Element>
    </ListOfElements>
    <ListOfSubelements>
        <Subelement ID="SubElem01" RelevantForFiltering="false"/>
    </ListOfSubelements>
</Document>
```

#### Expected XML output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
  <ListOfElements>
    <Element ID="Element01">
      <UseableSubelements>
            <SubelementReference Target="SubElem01" />
      </UseableSubelements>
    </Element>
    <Element ID="Element02">
      <UseableSubelements>
        <SubelementReference Target="SubElem01" />
      </UseableSubelements>
    </Element>
  </ListOfElements>
  <ListOfSubelements>
    <Subelement ID="SubElem01" RelevantForFiltering="false"/>
  </ListOfSubelements>
</Document>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanted to use `contains` you should define the variable like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="SubelementsToFilter">
  <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="//Subelement[@RelevantForFiltering='true']/@ID" separator=";"/>
  <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
```

And then the template match becomes this:

```
<xsl:template match="Element/UseableSubelements/SubelementReference[contains($SubelementsToFilter, concat(';', @Target, ';'))]"/>
```

This would get around the issue of `A-SubElem01, AB` containing `SumElem01`.

However, you don't need `contains` here. You can just define the variable like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="SubelementsToFilter" select="//Subelement[@RelevantForFiltering='true']/@ID" />
```

And then your template match becomes just this

```
<xsl:template match="Element/UseableSubelements/SubelementReference[$SubelementsToFilter = @Target]"/>
```

However, you can also achieve the same result with a key. Define a key to look up `Subelement` like so;

```
<xsl:key name="Subelements" match="Subelement" use="@ID" />
```

And then the template match becomes this:

```
<xsl:template match="Element/UseableSubelements/SubelementReference[key('Subelements', @Target)[@RelevantForFiltering='true']]"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

<xsl:key name="Subelements" match="Subelement" use="@ID" />

<!-- Identity transformation -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Remove Subelements -> working fine -->
<xsl:template match="Subelement[@RelevantForFiltering='true']"/>

<!-- Remove SubelementReferences -> too many items are removed -->
<xsl:template match="Element/UseableSubelements/SubelementReference[key('Subelements', @Target)[@RelevantForFiltering='true']]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution completely fulfil my requirement. No, I didn't really want to use "contains" - was just a try to solve my problem.